# foreach data from array return more than real data php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array data, this is in controller:

```
$infografis = $this->mapi->getInfografis(0, 5);

if (count($infografis) >= 1) {
    $content['widgetinfografis']  = $infografis;
  }
```

This infografis data contains 2 array. When I try to foreach to view, the data return more than 2.This is my foreach in view:

```
<?php if(!empty($widgetinfografis)):?>
        <!-- Infografis -->
        <div class="infografis">
            <div class="warp-infografis">
                <div class="title-section title-section-infografis">
                    INFOGRAFIS
                    <span>MORE<a href="<?php echo $more ?>"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></span>
                </div>
                <div class="warp-list-infografis">
                    <div class="swiper-infografis">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <?php $i = 1; foreach($widgetinfografis as $key => $value) { ?>
                            <article class="list-infografis swiper-slide">
                                <a href="<?php echo $value['link']; ?>">
                                    <div class="img-infografis">
                                        <img src="<?php echo image_uri().str_replace("thumb","master",$value['image_content']); ?>"
                                            alt="img-news">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="warp-detail-infografis">
                                        <div class="title-infografis">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $value['link']; ?>"
                                                class="title"><?php echo $value['title']; ?></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </article>
                            <?php $i++; } ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Infografis -->
        <?php endif;?>
```

This is the view in website (false, should showing 2 data)
[image: view picture]

**UPDATED**
This is my $widgetinfografis data
[image: widget]

**UPDATED**
I update full foreach data (swiper-wrapper)

Comment: Dump out `$widgetinfografis`, see what’s in there, ignore the html for now

Comment: Updated, I put this one to my question

Comment: Is this in a slider?

Comment: Yes, this is for slider

Comment: Is it possible that the slider JS is “filling in the blanks”? Can you view source, not inspect, and confirm that there’s more than 2?

Comment: I try to view source, and I found my data inside foreach showing 3 times. So when data contains 2, the data returns 6.

Comment: Is `<div class="swiper-wrapper">` repeated three times?

Comment: Yes. Please check again, I give full foreach data